# Rails Broadcast Logger with a Custom Logger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-7

in my project I'm using a custom logger which allows to send logs in this format:

```rb
Rails.logger.info('message', { arg_1: 'arg', arg_2: 'arg' })
```

I have the configured Rails so that when I call `Rails.logger` I get back an instance of my custom logger.

I'm currently upgrading from Rails 6x to Rails 7.1 and I noticed the introduction of the `ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger` object.

In order to get my custom logger, I now have to do `Rails.logger.broadcasts[0]` which is inconvenient as it would also mean having to do this everywhere I do a log around my application.

Is there a way to have a default custom logger in Rails or something similar which would still allow to return an instance of the custom logger when I call `Rails.logger` ?

I'm in the process of upgrading a Rails 6.x project to Rails 7.1 and encountered an issue with how logging is handled in the new version.

In my current setup, I use a custom logger that supports a specific logging format, which looks something like this:

```rb
Rails.logger.info('message', { arg_1: 'arg', arg_2: 'arg' })
```

This custom logger is configured so that calling `Rails.logger` returns an instance of it. However, after upgrading to Rails 7.1, I've noticed that `Rails.logger` now returns an `ActiveSupport::BroadcastLogger` object instead. This change requires me to access my custom logger via `Rails.logger.broadcasts[0]` which is not ideal since it would necessitate modifying numerous loggings throughout my whole app.

I'm looking for a way to maintain the previous behavior, where calling `Rails.logger` would directly return my custom logger instance. Is there a configuration or a decent workaround that allows for setting a default custom logger in Rails 7.1, effectively bypassing or integrating seamlessly with the new `BroadcastLogger` system?

Any guidance or insights into this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!